# How to avoid calling stale chunks with webpack and workbox?

Tags: webpack, service-worker, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm trying to understand service workers using Workbox and Webpack.

I have set up my webpack config to use chunks with chunkhash as names.  I have also set up Workbox to generate the SW for me.  However, the problem is that every time I rebuild my app and publish it, when the user calls for a chunk that has changed, they get the loader of death and nothing is loaded.  I do use CleanWebpackPlugin to clean out my dist folder before each build.

I believe that is because the SW is still calling for the old chunk with the old hashname, and it's no longer there.  When I close the app and reload it from scratch, it magically works.

I understand the SWs have that "delay" in their logic, and it will work on the next loadup.  But I need to handle the instance of the old hash chunk not being there somehow.

1. Should I keep around the old, outdated chunks?  If so, is there a
   way I can use a timestamp instead of a chunkhash name, so I will
   know which ones have been updated and can delete the old ones after
   a certain time?  Still not sure if that would solve the user's
   problem though.
2. Should I not use chunkhash names at all?
3. Is there a way to force the service worker to check for updates before calling for a chunk? If there is an update, use that, else use the cached one?  Would that slow me down too much?
4. Lastly, is there a way to tell the user "new version available".  I don't really want to do this, because it  would be annoying, as I'm in early days and publishing often.

I post here my relevant pieces of webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
      app: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash:4].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash:4].js', //name of non-entry chunk files
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),  //where to put the bundles
      publicPath: "/" // This is used to generate URLs to e.g. images
        },

...

plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: __dirname + '/public', to: __dirname + '/dist/public' } ]),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({filename: "[name].css"}),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       "template": "./src/template.html",
       "filename": "index.html",
       "hash": false,
       "inject": true,
       "compile": true,
       "favicon": false,
       "minify": true,
       "cache": true,
       "showErrors": true,
       "chunks": "all",
       "excludeChunks": [],
       "title": "ShareWalks",
       "xhtml": true,
       "chunksSortMode": 'none' //fixes bug
       })
   ]
```

Workbox piece:

```
 module.exports = merge(common, {
   mode: 'production',
   devtool: 'source-map',
   plugins: [
          new WorkboxPlugin.GenerateSW({ 
          // these options encourage the ServiceWorkers to get in there fast     
           // and not allow any straggling "old" SWs to hang around     
           clientsClaim: true,     
           skipWaiting: true
      }),
   ]
});
```

Comment: Hi, did you get this resolved?